# mongoose update nested document not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I try to figure out what I'm doing wrong that moongose is not updating my document. Just for testing the id's are hardcoded.

node.js

```
var id1 = "592fd471fedd311d5c76a024";
var id2 = "592fd4ad608e001d79938ba8";

Workshop.update({
        _id: id1,
        'themen._id': id2
    }, {
        '$set': {
            'themen.$.risikolandschaft': ["John", "Doe"],
        }
    },
    function(err, body) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            console.log(body);
        }
    }
);
```

here my data copied from MongoDB Compass

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("592fd471fedd311d5c76a024"),
"clientid" : "592cff8794738f0347609666",
"bezeichnung" : "Workshop 1.5.2017 / 10:46",
"themen" : [ 
    {
        "thema" : {
            "__v" : 0,
            "bezeichnung" : "Sturm",
            "beschreibung" : "Text",
            "_id" : "59255757b1485d0ad2a6924f"
        },
        "risikolandschaft" : [ "one", "two", "three"],
        "date" : "2017-06-01T08:47:41.944Z",
        "_id" : ObjectId("592fd4ad608e001d79938ba8")
    }
], ...
```

the log from body

```
{ n: 0, nModified: 0, ok: 1 }
```

for adding a new item to the "themen" subdocument i use this:

```
var new_thema = {
        _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
        date : req.body.date,
        risikolandschaft : req.body.risikolandschaft,
        thema : req.body.thema };
```

here the mongoose schema

```
var WorkshopSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    clientid: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    bezeichnung: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    stammdaten : [],
    date : Date,
    themen : []

});
```

and there is no subschema for "themen"
"mongoose": "^4.8.6"

Comment: Show your schema and the JSON view of the document. Something is incorrectly set as a string where it should be an `ObjectId` value so it is considered not to match.

Comment: Well you have a couple of problems by the look of it. The data path is actually `themen.thema._id` and it is indeed a "string". I would suggest your "mongoose schema" which I actually meant by "schema" for you to include in the question is also incorrect. It almost looks like this was migrated from a referenced format, but incorrectly.

Comment: Okay there is also `themen._id`. But it does look like schema problems as well. So your mongoose schema should make that clear.

Comment: thanks, i do not have a subschema for "themen" because i want to leave it as flexible as possible, i thought by using "_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId()", it's possible to access it by _id

Comment: You might want to turn on debug logging `mongoose.set("debug",true)`. I note that `themen` is only defined as an "array" and you did not actually define a Schema type to it. I'm thinking (well sure actually) that because of this, mongoose is leaving the supplied value at `themen._id` as a "string" when making the query. You probably really want to formalize the schema type for this array and then to `themen: [themenSchema]` to that declaration. Then the `ObjectId` values should cast correctly.

Comment: Thanks, you are right, a SubSchema is needed!